# Is an ESET antivirus 4 license valid for version 5?

Tags: license, nod32

I have already purchased ESET antivirus 4. Is this license valid for ESET antivirus 5?

Comment: Aren't the licenses time-based?

Comment: @slhck yeah but im afraid to install ver 5 and later to install ver 4 and to be blocked.

Comment: Contact the vendor directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to pop them a quick query here: http://www.eset.com/us/company/contact

It should be fine, as it is time based, but they'll be able to give you a definitive answer.